# Truffle, Contracts and Deploy

Tags: contract-development, ether, truffle, truffle-contract

I am following this [tutorial](https://blog.zeppelin.solutions/how-to-create-token-and-initial-coin-offering-contracts-using-truffle-openzeppelin-1b7a5dae99b6). Everything worked fine. Now I want to getBalanceOf tokens on my nodejs app, but I keep getting this error:

```
tokenContract.methods.balanceOf is not a function.
```

My code is as follows:

```
var provider = new web3.providers.HttpProvider(node.url);
            var w3 = new web3(provider);

            var tokenContract = new w3.eth.Contract(abi, query.token_address);

            console.log(tokenContract);

            w3.eth.call({
                to: query.pub_address,
                data: tokenContract.methods.balanceOf(query.pub_address).encodeABI()
            }).then(function(balance) {
                console.log(balance);
            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error)
                reject(error)
            })
```

If I check my tokenContract methods in console, by printing (tokenContract.methods) I see there is no balanceOf method exposed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried calling tokenContract.balanceOf() separately?

Comment: @RomanFrolov yes, I tried I get: tokenContract.balanceOf is not a function. If I print on console:  console.log(tokenContract.methods);. I do not see balanceOf method, if that is the problem how do I add it?

Comment: do you use correct contract abi?

Comment: @RomanFrolov I just found the issue, in the tutorial, they show to contracts: Coin and CrowdSale, I was using the CrowdSale which has no method getBalance since it seems is a different type of contract. Do you know the difference?

Comment: you can see the difference [here](https://www.ethereum.org/crowdsale)

Comment: As you can see with token contract you can just deploy some kind of currency or shares and play around with it. But with the crowdsale contract you can make a full fundraising campaign with a deadline and functionality to withdraw money in case of deadline.

Comment: @RomanFrolov can you add all this as an answer? So I can select it as the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was mentioned in the comment section below the question, the problem was that the CrowdSale contract was used instead of Token contract.
The reason of the error was that the contract `CrowdSale` doesn't have balanceOf() method.

Read more about [Crowd Sale contract](https://www.ethereum.org/crowdsale).

Read more about [Token contract](https://www.ethereum.org/token).